# google spreadsheet add only positive numbers from two different columns

Tags: google-sheets

I want to add column H2 with Column I2 with the Sum in J2, but only if the numbers in I2 is >=0.  If it is not >=0 then the total in J2 should just be the sum from H2

had a picture attached but since I am new, I can not post it.

Comment: Can you share what you've tried already and what the result of that was?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure If I understood your problem. say if u had 3 colums A,B and C and if B is >=0, u want to add A,B,C; This might work

=if(B2>=0,(sum(A2,B2,C2)),sum(A2,C2))

Basically just =if(condition,true_vale,false_value)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your suggestion, I figured out my answer late last night

=if(b2>0,(A2+B2),A2)

Basically if column be is Greater than 0 then add A2 +B2, if false then only give me the value of A2